# Nested resources and microservices: how to avoid monoliths?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, design-patterns, microservices, openapi-generator

I want to retrieve the address details of a person.

According to the REST specification I would have to have the following path:

```
GET /person/<person id>/address/<address id>
```

Now, suppose I want to retrieve the electronic addresses, I would have:

```
GET /person/<person id>/address/<address id>/electronic/<elec id>
```

And so on. 
While REST-wise it is fine, it can lead to a monolithic approach as the openapi generator (but also a person implementing it) would create one lone microservice handling several kind of data.

What could be another way to deal with this scenario?
I was thinking of:

**1-reversing the logic**

```
GET /addresses/<person id>/<address id>
GET /electronicAddresses/<person id>/<address id>/<electronic address>
```

**2- use headers/query string parameters and leave to single services**

```
GET /addresses/<address id>?person_id=
GET /electronicAddress/<elec id>?person_id
```

Can I have some practical directions? I feel that inner resource approach would explode in the end...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to decomposite your API and map it to a microservice architecture, like with the case with `address` and `person`.

If so, consider `address` and `person` how something independent, so there will be two services: `Person service` and `Address service`. Which will have next APIs:

```
GET /persons/{person_id}
GET /addresses/{address_id}
```

The question now, how to get the address of some person, since all address API doesn't have any person related request parameters. The answer is: **make two API calls**.

So, with the first request client retrieves person data by `person_id` which should contain some reference to address entity, like: `address_id`. With the second request now, a client can retrieve a person address by `address_id` parsed from personal data.

Comment: So no nested APIs at all?

Comment: You case use nested API here as you have described at #2. -`?personId=...`, this way to do it better. Since for Address entity, `personId` is just a field, so you can use it as a request param filter, which does not violate REST.

Comment: But, don't use #1. Second one much better.